# How to show an specific number of rows based on starter point

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show the last 50 rows of a table without using `"ORDER BY DESC"` cause of the ordering. Example:
If I do the next query

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 50");
```

I'll get the last 50 rows, just what I wanted to obtain but, the problem here is, if I echo the rows, it will start with the last Id and so on.

That's why I'm guessing a starter point as a solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this and understand the performance implications?

Comment: Im not concerned about the perfomance implications, I thought it wouldn't be too severe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM CHAT_TABLE WHERE ID IN (
     SELECT ID FROM (
        SELECT ID    
        FROM CHAT_TABLE
        ORDER BY TIME DESC
        LIMIT 50) TEMPTBL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store such a small list of chat messages temporarily and expire them automatically, you shouldn't be using an RDBMS, whose job is to store large amounts of data persistently.

Instead, consider using a message queue.  For example, [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: I believe that limit of 50 records must be for each user! :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the next solution to my problem:

```
$qId = mysqli_query($classDB->con,"SELECT id, message, userName FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); /* Getting the last Id of the table */
$rowId = mysqli_fetch_array($qId);
$index = $rowId['id'] - $limit; /* limit = number of rows that I want to show */
$qChat = mysqli_query($classDB->con,"SELECT id, message, userName FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $index, $limit"); /* $index is the starter point*/
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qChat) ){
// show messages
}
```

Comment: If that is really the solution, then you were asking the wrong question. :) It now appears that what you were actually after was how not to *show* everything rather than how not to *store* it.